# apache nutch taking too long time in generate phase

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I have two urls in my urls/seed file. My crawler taking too ling time before it start fetching. My already crawled data is about 220 GB . Any idea why nutch is behaving like this

Comment: You can limit the number of url's crawled using -depth and -topN parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before fetching job, the generating job is performed in Nutch. In the generating job, Nutch will select topN URLs, which have the highest scores among all URLs in CrawlDB, for fetching. Therefore the reason of your crawler taking too long time before fetching would be you set topN is too high compared to your system capacity, and the number of URLs in crawlDB is large (selecting process will take time).

Hope this helps

Le Quoc Do

Comment: If I select topN a small number, is there any drawback?

Comment: if you set topN, the number of URLs you get in each crawling round is also small.

Comment: is there a way to do limitless topN as I do not know exactly how many urls are there in database. Or What should be the configuration for a local language search engine to crawl but do not take too mutch time in  starting( generation)

Comment: I believe if you dont specify the topN there is no limit set.